# > Estimation of number of distinct integers in the sequence $a_i =\lfloor \frac{n}{n + 1 - i} \rfloor, i\geq 0$ for some given $n$

Tags: sequences-and-series, combinatorics, ceiling-and-floor-functions

The problem:

> Estimation of number of distinct integers in the sequence $a_i =\lfloor \frac{n}{n + 1 - i} \rfloor, i\geq 0$ for some given $n$

This problem is derived from a programming problem that I've solved. My algorithm gives $63245$ when $n = 10^9$.
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/1263/C

This is the best I've come up so far:

I've tried to evaluate the distance between two consecutive elements in the sequence, namely $a_i$ and $a_{i+1}$.
$$a_{i + 1} - a_i = \lfloor \frac{n}{n - i}\rfloor - \lfloor \frac{n}{n + 1 - i}\rfloor$$. Applying the properties of floor function, we can derive that:

$$\frac{n}{(n - i)(n - i + 1)} - 1\leq a_{i} - a_{i + 1} \leq \frac{n}{(n - i)(n - i + 1)} + 1$$. Roughly speaking, this means that the distance is around $\frac{n}{(n - i)(n - i + 1)}$.

This calculation fits with the sequence generated by my algorithm.
$$0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, ..., 1561, 1562, 1563, 1564, 1565,...,  80372, 80379, 80385, ..., 329924, 330033, 330141, 330250, 330360$$.

As $i$ grows large, the distance grows large quadratically. I'm stuck from here. Any help would be highly appreciated. Thank you for reading :D

Comment: Is that https://oeis.org/A000267 ?

Comment: @MartinR Hmm. Am I wrong somehow? How is this the same as my sequence? Did you mean this sequence? 1, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5, 5, 6, 6, 6, 7, 7, 7, 7, 8, 8, 8, 8, 9, 9, 9, 9, 9, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 11

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. – How did you come up with $0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10$ as the first elements? For example, if $n=5$ then the integer values of $5/k$ are $0, 1, 2, 5$, so the answer for $n=5$ is $4$. – Perhaps I misunderstand something?

Comment: And btw, A000267(n) = “Integer part of square root of 4n+1“ gives A000267(10^9) = 63245.

Comment: @MartinR Sorry. My terrible mistake. The above sequence is distinct elements listed in ascending order. Thank you for your help : D